# Labels and Dividing Lines in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

Below is a fiddle I have created using a basic D3 pie chart. I am new to D3 and not sure how to do a couple of things. First I would like to correct the labels. As you can see, the 'Correct' label is flying off the edge of the graph currently. But I am not sure how to fix this?

Second, I would like to add a black line around the graph and between the data slices to give the green and red contrast. If you have any ideas of how to do either, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/01qew1jk/

JS:

```
let incorrect = this.resLength - this.points;
    let correct = this.points;
    let data = [{
      'name': 'Correct',
      'points': correct
    },
    {
      'name': 'Incorrect',
      'points': incorrect
    }];
    let width = 400, height = 400, radius = Math.min(width, height)/2;
    let color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#15B61F', '#DA1821']);
    let pie = d3.pie().value(function(d){
      return d.points;
    })(data);
    let arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 10).innerRadius(0);
    let labelArc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 40).innerRadius(radius - 40);
    let svg = d3.select('#pie').append('svg').style('display', 'block').style('margin', '0 auto').attr('width', width).attr('height', height).append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + width/2 + ',' + height/2 + ')').attr('class', 'float-center');
    let g = svg.selectAll('arc').data(pie).enter().append('g').attr('class', 'arc');

    g.append('path').attr('d', arc).style('fill', function(d){
      return color(d.data.name)
    })
    g.append('text').attr('transform', function(d) {
      return 'translate(' + labelArc.centroid(d ) + ')';
    }).text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    }).style('fill', '#FFF')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positioning the texts, don't create a new arc generator with different outer and inner radii. Just use the same arc generator you used for the paths:

```
g.append('text').attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'translate(' + arc.centroid(d) + ')';
        //same generator ------^
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.name;
    })
    .style('fill', '#FFF')
```

To add that "black line", just set the path stroke:

```
.style("stroke", "black");
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
let incorrect = 3
let correct = 2
let data = [{
  'name': 'Correct',
  'points': correct
}, {
  'name': 'Incorrect',
  'points': incorrect
}];
let width = 400,
  height = 400,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
let color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#15B61F', '#DA1821']);
let pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
  return d.points;
})(data);
let arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 10).innerRadius(0);
let svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').style('display', 'block').style('margin', '0 auto').attr('width', width).attr('height', height).append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')').attr('class', 'float-center');
let g = svg.selectAll('arc').data(pie).enter().append('g').attr('class', 'arc');

g.append('path').attr('d', arc).style('fill', function(d) {
  return color(d.data.name)
}).style("stroke", "black")
g.append('text').attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + arc.centroid(d) + ')';
  }).text(function(d) {
    return d.data.name;
  }).style('fill', '#FFF')
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```